# Как создать событие onchange для field ActiveForm?

Tags: php, yii2, yii

Добрый день

YII 2

У меня есть следующее поле на форме ActiveForm:

```
<div class="col-sm-4">
        <?= $form->field($model, 'amount',
            ['options' => ['class' => 'form-group form-inline'],
            'onchange' => "
                if($('#dss-move_type').val() === '0'){    
                    var num = $(this).val();
                    num = num <= 0 : num ? -num;
                    $(this).val(num);
                }"]) ?>
    </div>
```

Но выдает ошибку: **Setting unknown property: yii\bootstrap\ActiveField::onchange**

Как правильно добавить onchange? Заранее спасибо за ответ

Comment: Для начала, попробуйте засунуть параметр `'onchange'` в массив `'options'`

Comment: если вы обратите внимание, у меня onchange yнаходится в options

Comment: Я именно на это и обратил внимание. Сейчас `onchange` находится НЕ в `option`. Посмотрите внимательнее

Comment: `onchange` должен быть на одном уровне с `class`

Comment: спасибо большое!